# French coordinate convertion

Tags: gis

I have an oldish (~2000) french guidebook where geographic coordinates are indicated in a system I don't know and I've been unable to find a suitable conversion. For instance, here are 2 points which I'm able to find on a map:

```
Guidebook1: X=850.41 Y=3312.28
Coord1:     5.51696E 45.06684N
Guidebook2: X=848.45 Y=3312.85
Coord2:     5.49209E 45.0728N
```

I've tried the following without success: Geographic (degrees, radians, grades), Mercator (km), Lambert 93 (km), Lambert II ext (km), UTM and a few other online converters. It seems to be kilometric and Lambert isn't too far off.

Any idea ?

Comment: You probably have more luck at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I DID look for something like that and was surprised no to find it (I did a search on StackExchange). Thanks